Windows Task Scheduler: run .py script without window opening
I have been asked to run a python script from the Windows Task Scheduler.
In my python script I will substantially use watchdog library in order to instanciate and run an Observer that will monitor file changes in a specific directory path
file_handlers.py
import time
import logging

from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

from elaboration_directory import FILE_PROCESS_DIR

logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


class FileHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):

    def on_created(self, event):
        if not event.is_directory:
            file_path = event.src_path
            logger.info('File added. File path: "%s"' % file_path)


class ElaborationFolderWatcher(object):

    def start(self):
        event_handler = FileHandler()
        observer = Observer()
        observer.schedule(event_handler, path=FILE_PROCESS_DIR, recursive=False)
        observer.start()
        logger.info('Observer: started')

        try:
            while True:
                # keep observer active
                time.sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            observer.stop()
        observer.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger.info('Python script started')
    elaboration_folder_watcher = ElaborationFolderWatcher()
    elaboration_folder_watcher.start()

My issue is that when I run the script from the Task Scheduler a terminal will open, and if I close it it will kill the process (and Observers).
Question
How can I run the python script from Windows Task Scheduler without opening any window?
Solution
Possible solution: instead of directly running the file_handlers.py I can run a .bat script that will call the file_handlers.py. By adding the argument pythonw.exe to the start command, no window will be opened.
run_program.bat (Target this file with Task Scheduler action)
@echo off

::Identify the path of directory containing python script using relative path

set SCRIPT_DIR=%~dp0
set PYTHON_SCRIPT=%SCRIPT_DIR%\file_handlers.py

:: Run the Python script. Argument "pythonw.exe" will avoid cmd opening

start "" "pythonw.exe" "%PYTHON_SCRIPT%" %*


Why don't you run without a terminal in the first place?

Certainly do not need a batch file to run a python script.

@tripleee I've been asked to keep the python script runnable from the "windows task scheduler" (It probably was worth mention, I will edit the question soon). I've just realized that I can simply run an action that runs "file_handlers.py" and it will work perfectly but a terminal will still open and as soon I close it the execution will be stopped.
